# What's the proper way to close a socket & avoid Errno 10054 with python/django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, selenium

I'm working with [django-selenium](https://django-selenium.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#) to run Selenium tests on a django app I'm involved with. This django app runs locally using Qt and a local webserver.

So to run tests I need to start the server for the app, the selenium server and then the webdriver instance to perform the tests.

django-selenium sets up it's server with a `subprocess.Popen('java -jar <path_to_server.jar>')` and then I run our webserver for the application similarly if the server isn't running;

```
def run():
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'main.py')
    server_running = is_server_running()

    if server_running is False:
        subprocess.Popen(['python', path, '-a'])
```

Now in the test setup looks like this;

```
def setUp(self):
    self.server = Process(target= startServer.run)
    self.server.start()
```

And to teardown;

```
def tearDown(self):
    # stop our server
    self.ff.get('http://localhost:{0}/QUIT'.format(settings.LISTEN_PORT))
    # stop the selenium server
    self.ff.get('http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer')
    # close the browser
    self.ff.quit()
    self.server.terminate()
```

Now in doing this, I get an `error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. I've tried adding `sleep` in between calls to close the connections but that didn't help.

Can you see where I'm perhaps making a mistake? I thought if the closure comes from the remote host then there shouldn't be a problem if I close our server first, then the selenium server and then terminate the process after the servers have shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well and I fixed it by refreshing the browser before quitting. (Yeah, weird, I know). Try adding this line before `self.ff.quit()`:

```
self.ff.refresh()
self.ff.quit()
```

That fixed it for me, although I have no idea why.

Comment: 2 years later and this strange fix still works, thanks! I'm using Django 1.8.4, with selenium 2.48.0.